# I am generating one programm to provide the information that related about lipiniski rule (for drug like molecule ) by providing users values

Tags: javascript

I am very new in this field. I would like to generate a program which lipinski rule of five that for drug like molecule. This rule has been established one. By providing the entered information, i would like to suggest whether it can be drug molecule or not. I am having problem in function part on my script. i couldnt get any output

```
<html>
<head>
<h1 align="center"><I><b>Lipinski's rule of five<b></h1>
</head>

<body>
 <form name=lipRule>
<b>Hydrogen Bond Donors</b>:<input type="number" name="HBD"><br/>
<b>Hydrogen Bond Acceptors</b>:<input type="number" name="HBA"><br/>
<b>Molecular Weight(dalton)</b>:<input type="number" name="MW"><br/>
<b>LogP</b>:<input type="number" name="LogP"><br/>
<input type="button" value="Result" onClick="lipinskiRule()"></br>
<b>As per your entered values, your drug is:</b><input type="text" name="rule"><br/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" style=color:purple;font-size:18px; ><br/>
</form>


<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function lipinskiRule()
{
var HBD=document.lipRule.HBD.value
var HBA=document.lipRule.HBA.value
var MW=document.lipRule.MW.value
var LogP=document.lipRule.LogP.value

if(HBD <=5 && HBA <=10 && MW <=500 && LogP <=5)
{
document.write("your drug molecule follows LIPINSKI'S rule")
}
}
else
{
document.lipRule.rule.value="your drug molecule doesn't follows LIPINSKI'S rule"
}
//-->
</script>

<style>
 body{background-color:lightblue;}
 h1{color:blue;background-color:lightgreen;}

</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your value to numbers (in this case with an unary `+`) and correct the condition, because it ends and takes then another curly bracket for closing.

Then you need a place for the output, without using `document.write`, because after rendering the page, you can not write somthing to the page with it. You could use an tag with `id` and take it for the output.

Hint: You could use the convention and use variable names with starting small letter and only starting with capital letters for classes or instanciable functions. All caps variable names denotes constant values.

```js
function lipinskiRule() {
    var HBD = +document.lipRule.HBD.value,
        HBA = +document.lipRule.HBA.value,
        MW = +document.lipRule.MW.value,
        LogP = +document.lipRule.LogP.value;

    if (HBD <= 5 && HBA <= 10 && MW <= 500 && LogP <= 5) {
        document.getElementById('conclusion').innerHTML = "your drug molecule follows LIPINSKI'S rule";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('conclusion').innerHTML = "your drug molecule doesn't follows LIPINSKI'S rule";
    }
}
```

```css
body { background-color: lightblue; }
h1 { color: blue; background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Lipinski's rule of five</h1>
<form name=lipRule>
<b>Hydrogen Bond Donors</b>:<input type="number" name="HBD"><br/>
<b>Hydrogen Bond Acceptors</b>:<input type="number" name="HBA"><br/>
<b>Molecular Weight(dalton)</b>:<input type="number" name="MW"><br/>
<b>LogP</b>:<input type="number" name="LogP"><br/>
<input type="button" value="Result" onClick="lipinskiRule()"></br>
<b>As per your entered values, your drug is:</b><input type="text" name="rule"><br/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" style=color:purple;font-size:18px; ><br/>
</form>
<p id="conclusion"></p>
```

Comment: Nina scholz.....thank you very much for your consideration. I have understood and u explained very nice manner

Comment: i forgot, inside of the `<head>` take, you can not insert some output tags, like `<h1>`.